# Profile Manager Lion Server error

Tags: osx-lion, mdm, device-manager

My Lion Server (10.7.1) worked perfectly until this tuesday. Yesterday when I went to profile manager's page, sometime it works and sometime not. 
Also, if I do the enrollment of a device sometimes works and sometimes not (I received a timeout). 
I discovered that port 5223 does not work, probably something happened to the Profile Manager? I have not done anything and the last time there were two updates info about 150 devices and sending two settings push about 150 users.

Help me guys, I'm really sad now :/.

[image: Half load profile manager]

Comment: Why is this tagged Ruby?

Comment: Sorry my error! I add Ruby because Profile Manager is build with Ruby on Rails.